# R: right input directory loads empty input.files and count.table

Tags: r, input, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to load multiple .tsv files and then combine the list of tables into one data frame.
Working on the right directory

```
"/Users/ecg1g15/samsa2/results"
```

When I run the following

> input.dir <- paste(getwd(),
>   'step_5_output/RefSeq_results/func_results', sep="/")
>
> input.files <- list.files(input.dir, pattern="*.tsv", full.names =
>   TRUE)
>
> input.filenames <- list.files(input.dir, pattern="*.tsv", full.names =
>   FALSE)
>
> input.names <- sapply(strsplit(input.filenames, "_"), "[", 1)

The values input.files and input.filenames are empty values and therefore I am generating an empty count.table later on.

I have checked those files exist within the input.directory path (also checked on the console by typing list.files(), those files aren't empty files, and I am working on the right directory.

Would anyone know how to fix this or can think where could be the problem here?

Thanks,

Elena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this work:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
file_names <- list.files(path = input.dir, pattern="*.tsv", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) 
your_data_frame <- do.call(bind_rows,lapply(file_names,read_tsv))
```

I prefer `read_tsv` to `read.tsv` and `bind_rows` to `rbind`

Comment: Unfortunately not.I tried and file_names is shown as "character (empty)" as well, and your_data_frame is "NULL (empty)"

Comment: What is the value in "input.dir" ? Are the files into sub-directories? If then, then using `recursive = T` is needed.

Comment: Ah! I got it! the value in input directory is /Users/ecg1g15/samsa2/R_scripts/step_5_output/RefSeq_results/func_results which means that the R script is not on the same directory as where I am. Does this mean the R script that I am running needs to be on the same directory as your working directory?